# How do I query a firebase database inside a cloud function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When a cloud function is triggered based on a specific parent node, how would I be able to query a different parent node within the cloud function, and then update the initial record (that triggered the cloud function) with the queried information? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a database function is triggered, it's delivered a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) of the data (or was previously, if it was a change).  DataSnapshot has a [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#ref) property of type [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) that points to the location of the data.  You can use that Reference to build other references by using its `parent` and `root` properties, or its `child()` method:

```
const root = snapshot.ref.root     // the root of your database
const users = root.child('users')  // the child node under root
```

You can also use the Admin SDK to build references to other locations, but using your existing ref is more efficient.  That ref is already backed by an initialized Admin SDK instance.

To learn how to use a reference, read the documentation on [reading](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) and [writing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) data.  Prefer to use once() on a reference to read.

Comment: Great, this is what I am looking for. Would I then be able to use that to make a query to the database? Example: using equalTo etc. @doug-stevenson

Comment: You can use those refs exactly as explained in the documentation for the Admin SDK that I linked to.  The refs come directly from the Admin SDK.